# Bought a 2 pack on Steam, but the second one isn't in my Inventory?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I bought a '2 pack' of 7 days to die. I can install the game, but the second access/copy/key isn't in my inventory as a 'gift'.

I wrote to Steam Support but did not get an answer. Can anybody advise me?

Comment: I bought a double pack couple years ago. Went fine back then. Just wait for steam support

Comment: Check your bank statement, make sure you've paid for the 2-pack

Answer (score 4):

We can't do anything about that. Wait for Steam Support to Reply.

Answer (score -1):

Look in your gifts page on Steam.

Comment: This question is 6 year old, you are a bit late..